# Write a typeracer

Tags: popularity-contest

## Description

a typeracer is an apps where user could type and evaluate their typing speed and accuracy.

## Criteria

- User could type "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
- A visual indicator of each wrong character typed.
- A visual indicator of what characters to type.
- A visual indicator of what has been typed
- A visual indicator of what hasn't been typed.
- After the last character is typed, shows time it took, WPM, and accuracy.

  - Time it took: since first character typed till the last character typed
  - WPM: round(right character typed/5)
  - Accuracy: right characters / all characters

Comment: Let me know if the Qs is against the rule

Comment: Like a duplicate

Comment: Note that [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) challenges are not so well received on this site any more.

Comment: In the future, please use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) before you post a challenge

Comment: Okay, Thanks everyone for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to code golf forum.
I've written a type racer with criteria above.

https://ramsicandra.com/type-racer.html

https://github.com/ramsicandra/simple-type-racer

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange). You might want to see the [Answering](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20863/114446) section for how to answer. You'll need to include your language name and code (rather than a link) in your answer, as this is a site for coding challenges.